# XPages Photo Slider with text

Tags: slider, xpages

I just want to create a small news database. I will take data from notesView only with 2 field. One of them is photo other one is subject.

For example ı have 10 documents.Slider will display photo and text together but text should be on the left photo should be on the right. then timeInterval should be 5 seconds. So slider will pass the next document every 5 seconds.

on this page There is a picture in the part of Turn.js close to the top. text stays on the left picture stays on the right. That is the picture of what exacly i am looking for.

http://www.turnjs.com is a really nice lohttp://xomino.com/2012/07/15/reviewing-3-javascript-presentation-libraries-for-my-mwlug-presentation/
any suggestion is important.
Regards
C.A.

Comment: This is what exacly i would like to do :)

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?9dPATS7v 
in this page you can see Demo1 with 3 subject. I will do it with 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a CSJS option you just need to generate static HTML in the correct format from your document data. A repeat control will do that. `removeRepeat="true"` will clear the panel that a repeat adds. Header and Footer facets on the repeat will also allow you to add HTML around the repeat body.

Comment: If you do not mind can you give me a specific names of design elements that can be used for. maybe relevant samples.
And I do not know how to generate static HTML 
Thanks

Comment: Here's an XSnippet for header and footer facets on a repeatControl https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=repeat-with-header-and-footer-facets